# Organisational search option

Tags: custom-search

I have three types of organisations: a. institution, b. supplier, c. corporate member.
I am creating different menus for manipulating each one of these (requirement of our users). I would like to offer a menu item that it called "Search for an institution" that when you press it, it has filtered the big list of organisations and displays only institutions. (the same for the other two categories).

How would I go about achieving something like this?

Thanks in advance

Aris

Answer (score 8):

Like Jon said auto filtering the search using url param is in progress. But a work around for this until its available is to

1. Create a smart group using advance search for each contact type.
2. Grab search id (civicrm_group.saved_search_id) of the smart group either from database or api.
3. Replace the id in the url for ssID `civicrm/contact/search/advanced?reset=1&ssID=1&force=1` and add it in your menu item.

Thanks

Pradeep

Answer (score 5):

Create the organizations as contact subtypes of the Organization type: **Administer menu » Customize Data and Screens » Contact Types**.  Now you can easily filter on them during search.

If you're talking about pre-filtering the search by institution, that's a feature that's in progress - you can pre-filter by some fields but not others (they need to be converted one at a time).  However, it's not fewer clicks to do this, so I think it's just easiest to show folks how to search by only one organization type when desired.